# How do I display with summaryCodings() only numbers of codings of a certain codecategory or several codes?

Tags: r, rqda

I'm using RQDA right now (for the first time) and I want to have an overview/comparison of the numbers of codings (to see which codes were used comparatively often, which were barely used).

I've tried `summaryCodings()` but it only gives me an overview of all codes.

How do I specify to make sure only certain codes (or, for example, one code category, and not all codes) are displayed?

I've tried variations like `summaryCodings(codename == "xy")` or `summaryCodings(codecategory == "xx")`, `getCodingTable(codename == "xy" | codename == "zy")`.

I'm a beginner so still learning how to manage RQDA (obviously). Thank you for your help in advance!

Answer (score 0):

This code will help you:

```
setwd("<working path>")
library("RMySQL")
con <- dbConnect(RSQLite::SQLite(), dbname="<database_name.rqda>")
answer <- dbGetQuery( con,'SELECT freecode.name, count(coding.cid) FROM treeCode, freecode, codecat, coding WHERE coding.cid = freecode.id AND treeCode.catid = codecat.catid AND treeCode.cid = freecode.id AND codecat.name = "<your option>" GROUP BY freecode.name')
dbDisconnect(con)
```

Now, you have the desired answer in 'answer' variable